# How to track mouse event and color the grid in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How do I draw a grid and track the mouse, where I'll change the color of the box where the mouse is hovering using Kivy?

Currently I have the code below, its not complete yet but having some issues.  With the way it currently is, it just tracks where the mouse is, without any of the grid drawn.  If i return just the layout, then the grid will be drawn but the mouse is not being tracked.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TouchInput(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(touch)
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        print(touch) ## WILL ADD CHANGING COLORS HERE LATER
    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        print("RELEASED!",touch)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        T = TouchInput()

        layout = GridLayout(cols=2)
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1'))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='World 1'))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 2'))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='World 2'))

        return T

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine your `TouchInput` methods and the `GridLayout` as:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(touch)
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        print(touch) ## WILL ADD CHANGING COLORS HERE LATER
    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        print("RELEASED!",touch)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        layout = MyGrid(cols=2)
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1'))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='World 1'))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 2'))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='World 2'))

        return layout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```